# Insert Data in Postgres from Python Using XMLRPC ? My code attached

Tags: java, python, postgresql, insert, xml-rpc

i am having python code i am calling it from android java. I want to insert data in Postgress my code is,

```
def Enterdetails():
    datas = request.body.read()
    datas = unicode(datas,errors='ignore')
    datas = json.dumps(datas)
    datas = json.loads(datas)
    data=ast.literal_eval(datas)
    dbname = data['dbname']
    username = data['uname']
    ip = data['ip']
    port = data['port']
    pwd = data['pwd']
    name = data['Name']
    address = data['Address']
    number = data['Number']
    url = 'http://'+ip+':'+port+'/xmlrpc/common'
    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)
    uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
    urls = 'http://'+ip+':'+port+'/xmlrpc/object'
    sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(urls)
    answer = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'parent.question', 'save_question', int(data['parent_id']), data['questions'])
    response.body = json.dumps(answer)
    return response
```

i am new to openerp XMLRPC can any one please tell me how to write

```
sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'parent.question', 'save_question', int(data['parent_id']), data['questions']))
```

so that i can insert data in table these are the data

```
name = data['Name']
    address = data['Address']
    number = data['Number']
```

in table Temp

hopes for your suggestion.